# ¿porque no me toma la interrupción de un GPIO?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Gente, el objetivo del siguiente codigo es tomar el dato binario de las entradas 23 y 24, almacenarlas en una archivo .txt cuando me detecte un Rising en el GPIO 21(Clock).

Cuando ejecuto el siguiente codigo y lo reviso paso por paso, observo que nunca toma la interrupción, se mantiene en el ciclo while esperando a cambie el estado de flag a true, lo que debería pasar cuando tome la interrupción de clock, cambiando flag a true.

Estoy seguro que cambio el valor de clock porque conecto el GPIO a la salida 3.3v de la  Raspberry  que se encuentra en DOWN.
El contador es para observar si hay algún cambio en el codigo o si toma la interrupción.

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) # formato para utilizar los pines de la rasberry

Clock = 21
Data1=23
Yb=24

global flag

flag= ()

global contador


GPIO.setup(Clock,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(Data1,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(Yb,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)


def captura (self):
    flag=True
    
    
archivo = open("datos.txt", "a")  

contador=0

GPIO.add_event_detect(Clock, GPIO.RISING,callback=captura)

t=time.time()
while (time.time()-t<10):
    
    if flag==True:
      salida=str(int(GPIO.input(Data1)))
      salida=salida+' '+str(int(GPIO.input(Yb)))+'\n'
      flag=False
      archivo.write(salida)
      contador = contador+1
    
      print ("its work")
      
      
print (contador)
archivo.close()
```

Comment: Te faltó el global flag dentro de la función captura. Sin ese global, Python cree que estás creando una variable local (que solo existe dentro de la función).

Comment: buenaaaaa broooo muchas gracias